# Array Out of Bound Exception in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am just sorting an array and my code seem to be fine but I am unable to resolve the Array Out of Bound Exception. Any ideas.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int temp = 0; // For temporary holding array values for swapping

    int [] num = new int[] {1, 4, 7, 6, 9, 3, 0, 8, 5, 2 };

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) //Outer loop
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) // Inner loop
        {
            if (num[j] > num[j + 1])
            {
                temp = num[j + 1];
                num[j + 1] = num[j];
                num[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //Displaying the array 
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(num[i]);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Guys, the piece of code that I have posted is when I replaced the j<=9 with j<9 and this gives me correct answer except that one element of array is not sorted. Before replacing the code was giving me Array Out of Bound exception.

Comment: Actually this is my first week of jumping into programming and I really am not used to use debugger... Sorry about that.

Comment: Use `num.Length` instead of `9`, that'll be a good start

Comment: @DanielJ.: The good news is that now is a great time to practice using a debugger.  With it you can step through the code, line by line, as it executes and see exactly what the runtime values are.  You can stop execution at the time of the exception and see what the runtime values are when that happens.  This will help you determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: The debugger is your friend.  Debugging in Visual Studio is pretty easy.  Just keep pressing F10 to step through, line by line.

Comment: Well, it seems that I am printing only 9 values, in the last loop for displaying the array, I have replaced the i<9 to i<=9 and it is working just fine. I am Okay I guess...

Comment: Looks like there are several things in this question which could be improved. For example, do you intend to print out only up the the 8th index at the end of the code? I also recommend using num.Length to keep it dynamic.

Comment: There is no error in your code above (just the final for needs to have an upper bound set to 10 but this doesn't trigger the error. So this is not the code that produces the out of bound message

Comment: This is  such a helpful community, would love to be a part of it guys. Thanks everyone,.

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)

Comment: You should probably read the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the second loop to "j < loopSize - i" (instead of j < loopSize) will double the efficiency of your bubble sort. :)

```
       int[] num = new int[] { 1, 4, 7, 6, 9, 3, 0, 8, 5, 2 };
        //int comparisons = 0;
        int loopSize = num.Length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= loopSize; i++) //Outer loop
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < loopSize - i; j++) // Inner loop
            {
                //comparisons++;
                if (num[j] > num[j + 1])
                {
                    temp = num[j + 1];
                    num[j + 1] = num[j];
                    num[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        //Displaying the array 
        for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(num[i]);
        //Console.WriteLine("comp: {0}", comparisons);
        //Console.ReadKey();
    }
```